# Pagination in CakePHP 2.0

Tags: cakephp

I use CakePHP 2.x and have a thread with many posts in it, which I want to paginate. But when I take a look into the sql-log, there is a SELECT-statement which affects ALL the posts (25k) of the thread. Actually there are only 20 Posts displayed, so is there a way to avoid this overhead?

Here is the code of my ThreadsController

```
public function view($id = null) {
    $this->Thread->id = $id;
    $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'thread_id' => $id,
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'Post.id' => 'DESC')
    );
    if (!$this->Thread->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid thread'));
    }

    $this->set('thread', $this->Thread->read(null, $id));
    $this->set('posts', $this->paginate('Post'));
}
```

Here is the SQL-query which affects all the 25k rows:

SELECT `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`user_id`, `Post`.`post`, `Post`.`created`, `Post`.`modified`, `Post`.`thread_id` FROM `ppv3`.`posts` AS `Post` WHERE `Post`.`thread_id` = (1)

Comment: You wanna post your code and the sql queries? If there one that affects all as you say, is that the count query?

Comment: edited my question. unfortunately it is not the count query

Comment: It looks like there's another query somewhere... None of what you have in that action should generate that query, except if the pagination one ignored the order for some reason.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I commented out all the code related to the pagination and the query was still there! by adding "$this->Thread->recursive = 0;" I finally got rid of it

Answer (score 1):

You should look at your queries, then use cakePHP custom pagination method. [Cakephp Custom Query Pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination). You can override the default paginate method. Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for the answer, the solution however was just one line: "$this->Thread->recursive = 0;"

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine with your code except that you did not defined the "limit" in pagination i.e. how many records you want to fetch for a single page.

Your controller's method should looks like:

```
public function view($id = null) {
$this->Thread->id = $id;
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 20, // this was the option which you forgot to mention
    'conditions' => array(
        'thread_id' => $id,
    ),
    'order' => array(
        'Post.id' => 'DESC')
);
if (!$this->Thread->exists()) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid thread'));
}

$this->set('thread', $this->Thread->read(null, $id));
$this->set('posts', $this->paginate('Post'));
}
```

Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply but defining "limit" is no improvement.